# Interpreting valgrind error Invalid write of size 4

Tags: gcc, valgrind

I was recently trying to track down some bugs in a program I am working on using valgrind, and one of the errors I got was:

```
==6866== Invalid write of size 4
==6866==    at 0x40C9E2: superneuron::read(_IO_FILE*) (superneuron.cc:414)
```

the offending line # 414 reads

```
amplitudes__[points_read] = 0x0;
```

and amplitudes__  is defined earlier as

```
uint32_t * amplitudes__ = (uint32_t* ) amplitudes;
```

Now obviously a uint32_t is 4 bytes long, so this is the write size, but could someone tell me why it's invalid ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`points_read` is most likely out of bounds, you're writing past (or before) the memory you allocated for  `amplitudes`.

Answer (score 4):

A typical mistake new programmers do to get this warning is:

```
struct a *many_a;
many_a = malloc(sizeof *many_a * size + 1);
```

and then try to read or write to the memory at location 'size':

```
many_a[size] = ...;
```

Here the allocation should be:

```
many_a = malloc(sizeof *many_a * (size + 1));
```